# IMS init empty DB

Tags: jcl, dbd, ims-db

i've got a problem, that i can't resolve.
I want to try to work with IMS. so i make dbdlib, psblib, and now write jcl to init my db.

```
1://RELOAD    EXEC PGM=DFSRRC00,PARM='ULU,DFSURGL0,LIBDBD,,,,,,,,,,,N' 
2://STEPLIB     DD DISP=SHR,DSN=DFSD10.SDFSRESL                        
3://DFSRESLB    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=DFSD10.SDFSRESL                        
4://IMS         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=USER19.DBDLIB                          
5://DFSUINPT    DD DUMMY                                               
6://DFSVSAMP    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=DFSD10.PROCLIB(VSAMP01)                
7://SYSPRINT    DD SYSOUT=*                                            
8://DATABASE    DD DISP=OLD,DSN=USER19.LIBIMS
```

This is my jcl. I've got rc 16 and such msgs in sysprint:

**DFS386A    A PREMATURE EOF WAS ENCOUNTERED ON DDNAME DFSUINPT**

**DFS339I    FUNCTION DR HAS COMPLETED ABNORMALLY RC=16**

I think, he want me putting some data in my db, but i only want to init EMPTY db

Comment: You should have a DBA who can assist with this. Any "empty" IMS DB that has never had data doesn't really exist. See here: http://www.slideshare.net/danjodea/basic-ims-for-applications

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should be using DFSURGL0 as that's reload/unload utility as per

> The HD Reorganization Reload utility (DFSURGL0) reloads databases and HALDB partitions by using the output data sets that are created by the HD Reorganization Unload utility (DFSURGU0).

I'd suggest haveing a look at the IBM Knowledge centre. This could be a good starting point as it's the initialisation utilities. [Definition and initialization utilities](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPH2_13.1.0/com.ibm.ims13.doc.dur/ims_dur02.htm)

I can't be of much more help as it's been around 30 years or since I last used IMS Utilities and only have access to search the web in this respect.

In brief terms what you've encountered is the utility saying it expects some data in the ddname DFSUINPT and DD DUMMY results in END of DATA (EOF) immediately the DDNAME is accessed/read. So DFSURGL0 is complaining, hence CC=16. Another way of looking at this is that you told it, perhaps by default, to load the database, so it's saying what with.

Comment: I don't think it matters what utility you use. You can't have a usable "initially empty" IMS DB in the sense that is being attempted. You can't load it with "nothing".

Comment: I believe that you need to load it with one record. You can then delete all the records afterwards leaving it empty and that's fine, but to start with you need one record.

I just wrote a little batch program to do it with a loading PSB.